# I think I've found an invariant distribution for a transient discrete Markov chain - Where is my mistake?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Let

- $E$ be an at most countable set equipped with the discrete topology $\mathcal E$
- $X=(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ be a discrete Markov chain with values in $(E,\mathcal E)$, distributions $(\operatorname P_x)_{x\in E}$ and transition matrix $$p=\left(p(x,y)\right)_{x,y\in E}:=\left(\operatorname P_x\left[X_1=y\right]\right)\;.$$
- $\tau_x^1:=\inf\left\{n\in\mathbb N:X_n=x\right\}$ and $$\varrho(x,y):=\operatorname P_x\left[\tau_y^1<\infty\right]$$

> A measure $\mu$ on $(E,\mathcal E)$ is called **invariant** $:\Leftrightarrow$ $$\mu p=\mu\;,\tag 1$$ where $$\mu p\left(\left\{x\right\}\right):=\sum_{y\in E}\mu\left(\left\{y\right\}\right)p(y,x)\;\;\;\text{for }y\in E\;.$$ If $\mu$ is a probability measure with $(1)$, it's called an **invariant distribution**. Moreover, $x\in E$ is called **transient** $:\Leftrightarrow$ $$\varrho(x,x)<1\;.$$

[At the German Wikipedia page](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Station%C3%A4re_Verteilung#Existenz_und_Eindeutigkeit), they state, that if $X$ is *transient*, i.e. all states are transient, then there exists no invariant distribution.

However, I think, that I've found a counterexample:

- Consider the *random walk* on $\mathbb Z$ with transition probabilities $$p(x,x+1)=r\;\text{and}\;p(x,x-1)=1-r\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb Z$$ for some $r\in (0,1)$
- Let $$\mu_1\left(\left\{x\right\}\right):=1\;\text{and}\;\mu_2\left(\left\{x\right\}\right):=\left(\frac r{1-r}\right)^x\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb Z$$ and $\mu_1(\emptyset):=\mu_2(\emptyset):=0$

It's easy to see, that $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ both satisfy $(1)$. Moreover, if $r\ne 1/2$, the random walk is transient and $\mu_1\ne \mu_2$. In addition, each non-negative linear combination of $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ is an invariant measure, too.

> While these combinations are no invariant *distribution* in general, at least $\mu_1$ should be one. So, I think I've found an invariant distribution of a transient discrete Markov chain. Is this the world's end or did I made a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made more than one mistake. You mistranslated the German Wikipedia article – it doesn't talk about measures (Maß) but about distributions (Verteilung). You also seem to be equivocating between measures, probability measures and distributions in your arguments in English. The counting measure is indeed invariant under these transitions, but it's neither a probability measure nor a distribution.

Comment: No, I've not mistranslated the article. Please notice, that I distinguish between invariant measures and distributions in my question. And I don't equivocate any terms. The only mistake I've made, is that I thought $\mu_1$ would be a probability measure. For some reason, I thought it would assign a constant value of $1$ to any measurable set, but that's obviously not the case. I've defined $\mu_1$ only for the unit sets (since that determines this measure uniquely) and I think, that this led to the confusion.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Why argue? The paragraph "Existenz und Eindeutigkeit" starts with: "Im Allgemeinen müssen keine stationäre **Verteilungen** existieren. Beispiel hierfür sind transiente Markow-Ketten. Diese besitzen nie stationäre **Verteilungen**."

Comment: @Did I've no idea what you mean. As I've said before, I thought $\mu_1$ is a probability measure (which is obviously wrong). Since $\mu_1$ is invariant, it would be called an invariant **distribution**.

Comment: @Did In the context of this question: I've defined $X$ to be a process with "distributions $(\operatorname P_x)_{x\in E}$". What's meant is, that$$\operatorname P_x\left[X_0=x\right]=1\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in E\;.$$ In the context of invariant distributions, I frequently read about a so-called *initial distribution $\pi$* of $X$ and what's meant is, that $$\operatorname P\left[X_0\in A\right]=\pi(A)\;\;\;\text{for all }A\in\mathcal E$$ where $\operatorname P$ is a probability measure on the measurable space on which $X$ is defined. How do these two definitions correspond to each other?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Are you for real? You: "At the German Wikipedia page, they state, that if X is transient, i.e. all states are transient, then there exists no invariant **measure**." joriki: "You mistranslated the German Wikipedia article – it doesn't talk about **measures** (Maß) but about **distributions** (Verteilung)." You: "I've not mistranslated the article." WP: "Im Allgemeinen müssen keine stationäre **Verteilungen** existieren." O well...

Comment: @Did That was a typo and I think you should have noticed that, since I've closed the question by stating "I think I've found an invariant distribution of a transient discrete Markov chain".

Comment: @0xbadf00d: A typo is when you type one or two letters wrong. Calling a distribution a measure is not a typo, and especially not when these are the central concepts that you're writing about and you're quoting a text in translation.